60s/70s Cartoon villain with large *white* moustache
Background: I have a vague memory of a specific (perhaps unnamed) villain in one of the vast number of TV cartoons I watched as a kiddie. I have been trying to track this villain down since 2007, to no avail.
As I recall, the villain I have in mind was in a series (that is, he was not a 'one-off'); I am reasonably sure that it was a series that had a similar animation style to 'Batfink (and Karate!)', 'Mr. Magoo' and 'Rocky & Bullwinkle' (stylised buildings etc.), but not as stylised as 'Roger Ramjet'.
The character wore a grey suit and a bowler (or a similar hat): perhaps a banker? He was stout, and the moustache was a 'one piece' job that was quite like Ned Flanders'.  It was not Boris, or Dick Dastardly, or Snidely Whiplash - fine villains all; it was not a weak villain like Professor Von Gimminck from Atom Ant. 
For the life of me, I cannot recall his voice, which means it wasn't 'characterised'.
The nearest I have seen to the moustache in question is this image of John Bolton: in fact, the moustache is so similar that now I think that the baddie in question probably also had glasses - but probably didn't try to force his then-wife to participate in ménages à trois.
Anybody? Bueller?


Hi. Do you remember anything he did or said or who fought him, however vaguely?

Could it be Professor Nutty Nutmeg ?

Pretty sure that's my guy. That's an awesome get, given my mis-remembering of his getup - got the guy's clothing about as wrong as it's possible to do (it's not grey; it's not a suit; he doesn't wear a hat). Shows how mutable memory is: I was fairly sure that he dressed like Mr Magoo. Given that I watched soooo many different cartoons as a kiddie, perhaps it's not surprising that I misremembered... but given that I can recite the song to most of 'em (including Felix, which I watched probably 30 times), it's weird that I got the dude's clothes so wrong.

@GT: No big deal, glad that one was the one! I stuck to the specific mustache detail without worrying too much about the rest.
